# Execute python script -- Ajax and Flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I apologize if this is unclear or anything like that. I'm very very new to web programming of any kind, so please be patient. When a link is clicked, I want to run a python script and then display the results. What is currently happening is it's just returning the HTML page. I have an *idea* of why but no clue how to fix it. I believe the issue is with the Flask python code, but please any input is appreciated. I will comment the area I believe to be the problem

Flask (Python) code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, world!"

@app.route('/cgi-bin/cputemp.py', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
#this is where  need to put something, but I don't know what. 
#Without defining this route I was getting a 405 error. I have no idea
#what would go here -- this is just the directory to the python and I 
#thought the routes were for different web pages the user could access.
#Again, I believe *this* is the source of the problem. Obviously 
#right now it's just returning the HTML of the following test() function.


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    return render_template("test.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/static/test.js"></script> 
<div id="swiss"><a href="javascript:cputemp2()">Click to display CPU Temp</a></div>

</html>
```

test.js

```
function cputemp2()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "cgi-bin/cputemp.py",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg)
        {
        console.log(msg); # It's just returning the HTML of test.html currently
        document.getElementById('swiss').innerHTML = msg;
        },
    });
}
```

cputemp.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi;
import cgitb;
import time
cgitb.enable()
import commands
import sys
import string
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
mytemp1 = commands.getoutput('/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | cut -d "=" -f2 | cut -f1')
output = "Pi CPU Temp is: " + mytemp1
print output
```

My question is -- I thought the AJAX code in the test.js file would be handling the call to the python script. All it does is execute the method below the route to that directory in my Flask code. So do I need to run the python code there? How do I do this?

Thank you *so* much, I'm really  lost and stuck on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things here that need to be fixed to get things working (or at least how I understand you want them to work).

If you're going to be using Flask, you don't need the route to point to a Python script. You can route to something like `/cputemp` and then run a function that returns the piece of HTML with the CPU temp that I presume you wanted to display.

```
@app.route('/cputemp', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def cputemp():
    mytemp1 = commands.getoutput('/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | cut -d "=" -f2 | cut -f1')
    return render_template("cputemp.html", temp=mytemp1)
```

Don't forget to import `commands` at the top. Although, you really should be using `subprocess` instead. https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html

The return there uses a Flask template to create the HTML fragment that you want to insert when the AJAX request is successful. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#rendering-templates

For example, `cputemp.html` can simply be something like:

```
<p>Pi CPU Temp is: {{ temp }}</p>
```

**Note that I don't know whether that command being assigned to `mytemp1` works.** That's a separate issue from not being able to display the information you want.

Now for the AJAX part. I added an error handler to help debug further issues. Note that I changed the URL to match the route. Also, using `innerHTML` has security issues, and rather than concerning yourself with sanitizing what you set `innerHTML` to, use jQuery's `html` function. http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
function cputemp2() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cputemp",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            $("#swiss").html(msg);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this is enough to get you moving along.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info, it's really useful. This is a general sort of issue I wanted to resolve -- displaying sensor data dynamically on a website. It seems like you removed the python script entirely and replaced it with the line in cputemp(), is this correct? This would work for this specific case but I was wondering how it would be done in a more general case where I want to execute an external Python script. Am I misunderstanding this? Thanks again,

Comment: Yes, I moved the logic from the script to a function that gets executed when the client requests its respective route. If it's an external script you have no control over, I would still resort to using `subprocess` to running that external script and using its result accordingly.

But if you have full control of where you decide to put your logic, I don't see the point of separating it into another script when you could just include in your Flask app. Or you could organize that script as a module with particular functions that you could import into the app.

Comment: I will try to do that, thanks a bunch. This has been extremely helpful. Do you know how to update it dynamically? Such as -- sensor data which is constantly changing and updating a number on the webpage?

Comment: I don't know the exact implementation, but I would look into web sockets for things where you need a server to push data to the client.

Comment: @skex you could also just do the ajax call every 5 seconds or whatever.

Comment: Isn't the return of the flask method what displays the actual page? I didn't think there was any way to put that in a loop, because the URL triggers that function call.

Comment: Also the ajax call won't call the python script which is my problem in the first place.

Comment: @skex I think what syntonym was saying was that you can loop the AJAX request on the client side. Basically a `setTimeout` in your Javascript that makes that request at certain intervals. As it makes each AJAX request, it will get that HTML fragment response and substitute it into the inner HTML of the designated element. It's only another (quicker and easier) way to implement automatic updates on the page.

Comment: You're right, for some reason I was thinking it wasn't re-rendered until the return_template in the Flask python file but that could work. Thank you.