# Flask/Python and Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, templates, flask

I found this which looks very close to what I'm trying to achieve.  This is my first Python project and I know nothing about Ajax so I'm not sure what I'm looking at:

[Execute python script -- Ajax and Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557814/execute-python-script-ajax-and-flask)

I get the first box with the Flask route - I'm doing that, but with lots of variable.

I get the second box with the html that displays the variable passed from the Flask route.

It's the last box that I'm struggling with.

In my template I have:

```
<div id="insidetemp">
    <i class="fas fa-thermometer-half"></i> {{ intTemp }}&#8451;
</div>
<div id="heatingtarget">
    <i class="fas fa-fire"></i> {{ targetTemp }}&#8451; <i class="far fa-clock sm"></i>
</div>
```

These are all generated from my / route.

He has:

```
function cputemp2() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cputemp",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            $("#swiss").html(msg);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

So, I guess I can change the name of the function.  I'd change the URL to /.  I'd change the id to #insidetemp to target the div in my template.

I'm going to take a stab at the first bit:

```
function syncvalues() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                $("#insidetemp").html(msg);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

But how would I add more variables?  If someone can get me started with 2 variables then I'm hoping I can extend that to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way would be to have your endpoint return a JSON encoded dictionary, like:

```
{
    "insidetemp": 37,
    "fanspeed": 2800
}
```

and then parse this in the browser using JSON:

```
let data = JSON.parse(msg)
```

and then get values out as you want

there are various tutorials around that describe this sort of thing much better

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I think you've answered the question.  If I'm right, then what you're saying is that the (msg) bit will hold the response which could be one variable or lots of variables or anything else I choose; but it's the (msg) bit that is important.

Comment: the `msg` is the "thing" that comes back from the server…  your existing code was treating it as a single bit of html, switching it to a JSON object lets you put more in the response as well as helping with separating concerns — server just generates a nice formal JSON object, the web client worries about putting it in the right place